# Is it possible to log out from Facebook

Tags: c#, ios, facebook, xamarin

I added a Facebook login in my app. When I log in in my application it also logs in toSAFARI so that next time when I want to login, I don't need to enter login and password. You might press continue and you already login. I created a method to log out but it's not working. Its working in a simulator so I can close my app then open Safari and go to Facebook.com then press logout. Finally I open my app press press the Facebook login and got login and password fields.

```
public void Logout()
{
    _loginManager.LogOut();
    NSHttpCookieStorage storage = NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage;
    foreach (NSHttpCookie cookie in storage.Cookies) 
    {
        if(cookie.Domain == ".facebook.com")
        {
            storage.DeleteCookie(cookie);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I log out from FB to every time enter login and password?

This image show that my credentials already entered:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are maybe looking for methods and classes from WebKit instead. Also refer to this Forum post: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/149720/delete-web-cache-javascript-storage

You can get cookies and sessions with (there are more types in WKWebsiteDataType if there are other things you want to clear):

```
var websiteDataTypes = new NSSet<NSString>(
    WKWebsiteDataType.Cookies,
    WKWebsiteDataType.SessionStorage);
```

Or you can use `WKWebsiteDataStore.AllWebsiteDataTypes` to just clear everything.

You can then fetch these types with:

```
WKWebsiteDataStore.DefaultDataStore.FetchDataRecordsOfTypes()
```

It has a callback you need to listen to, to get these. Then you can remove all these records with:

```
WKWebsiteDataStore.DefaultDataStore.RemoveDataOfTypes();
```

Put it all together like:

```
var websiteDataTypes = new NSSet<NSString>(
    WKWebsiteDataType.Cookies,
    WKWebsiteDataType.SessionStorage);

WKWebsiteDataStore.DefaultDataStore.FetchDataRecordsOfTypes(websiteDataTypes, records => 
{
    for (nuint i = 0; i < records.Count; i++)
    {
        var record = records.GetItem<WKWebsiteDataRecord>(i);
        WKWebsiteDataStore.DefaultDataStore.RemoveDataOfTypes(
            record.DataTypes,
            new[] {record}, 
            () => {}
        );
    }
});
```